# Partial interpretation of an iteration

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Suppose that $\langle\mathbb{P_\alpha,\dot Q_\beta}\mid \beta<\delta,\alpha\leq\delta\rangle$ is a system of iterated forcing.

Let $\dot a$ be a name in $\mathbb P_\delta$, and let $G_\alpha$ be a generic for $\mathbb P_\alpha$ for $\alpha<\delta$. Is there a reasonable sense in which we can interpret $\dot a$ using $G_\alpha$?

If so, is the result of this partial interpretation a $\mathbb P_{\alpha\delta}$-name (i.e. the quotient forcing) for $\dot a$?

(If it matters, we can assume that the iteration is finite support, but a general answer would be great.)

Comment: This is exactly what Blass and Shelah do in their paper "Ultrafilters with Small Generating Sets."  On page 269 there, they "let f' be obtained by evaluating the [...] name f " (with respect to a generic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand\P{\mathbb{P}}\newcommand\Q{\mathbb{Q}}$

Yes. Perhaps it is easier to think about the case of two-step iterations, which contain the whole story. Namely, from any $\P*\dot\Q$-name $\dot a$ we may in a canonical manner construct a $\P$-name for a $\dot\Q$-name, let us call it $\ddot a$, such that if $V\subset V[G][H]$ is the forcing extension first by $G\subset\P$ and then by $H\subset\Q=\dot\Q_G$, then $\dot a_{G*H}=(\ddot a_G)_H$. That is, $\ddot a$ is a name for an object in $V[G]$ that will be a $\Q$-name for the object in $V[G*H]$ named by $\dot a$. One may view it as an exercise in parenthesis-rearranging to construct $\ddot a$ from $\dot a$, if you think about what needs to be in $\ddot a$, given what is in $\dot a$. So you can make a recursive definition working directly with the names.

But also, you can see abstractly that this must be true, simply because $V[G*H]=V[G][H]$, so every object in $V[G*H]$ is the result of interpreting a $\Q$-name in $V[G]$ by the filter $H$. In particular, $\dot a_{G*H}$ must be $\tau_H$ for some $\Q$-name $\tau$ in $V[G]$, and $\tau$ itself must be $\ddot a_G$ for some $\P$-name (of a $\dot\Q$-name) $\ddot a$.

Your case of iteration is just like this simple two-step iteration, if you think of the iteration up to stage $\alpha$ as one step, and then the rest of the iteration from $\alpha$ to $\delta$ as the second step.

Comment: Thank you Joel. I am well aware of the canonical translations. I am wondering if we can do without these somehow. I'll think about what you said some more. Thanks again!

Comment: The parenthesis-rearranging proof produces an $\ddot a$ that depends only on $\dot a$ (and the forcing notions). Does the more abstract approach in your second paragraph achieve that? It seems to me that it produces a $\ddot a$ that could depend on $G$ or (horrors!) on $H$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I agree with you that the direct proof is superior in that respect, and furthermore, the direct way of reasoning is already present in some of the typical ways to prove that $V[G*H]=V[G][H]$ in the first place. With a suitable mixing argument, however, it seems that one can make the abstract approach have the extra property, but the resulting argument is closer to the parenthesis-rearranging direct approach...

Comment: @Asaf Since Joel's answer is not what you were looking for, could you perhaps give a clue on what you plan to do with such a name? I mean, what is for you a "reasonable sense" to interpret that name?

Comment: @Ioanna: I'm not 100% sure yet. Which is why I posted this question. I was hoping that something like "complete the generic on $\mathbb P_\alpha$ to a generic on $\mathbb P_\delta$ by adding $1$ on the interval $[\alpha,\delta)$" or something like that. But I'm still not done thinking about Joel's answer, so it might be that it is the answer I'm looking for.